# Why am i getting no results from my stored proc?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am executing the following stored procedure using the code but i am not getting any results, can someone help and explain where i'm going wrong?

This is my SP;

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchFilms] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@type varchar(20),
@value varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
Select * from tblFilm where @type like CONCAT('%', @value,'%');
END
```

I am passing the following parameters
 @type = 'Title'
 @value = 'Sam'

I am expecting this to return everything where Title column contains the name Sam, instead it returns nothing.

Comment: You are going to need to use `dynamic sql` to build the `select` statement.  You cannot dynamically pass in the table name without.

Comment: @sgeddes you mean field name.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Side note (if this is for **SQL Server**): you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

It is returning nothing because it is throwing an error.  You are not checking for it throwing an error.

Try something like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchFilms] 
@type varchar(20),
@value varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT *
FROM tblFile 
WHERE 
  title LIKE CASE WHEN @type = 'title' then CONCAT('%', @value,'%') ELSE title END
AND
  director LIKE CASE WHEN @type = 'director ' then CONCAT('%', @value,'%') ELSE director END
-- etc
END -- ALTER PROCEDURE
```

Personally I like this better:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_SearchFilms] 
@title varchar(50) = null,
@director varchar(50) = null
-- etc, parameter for each search term
AS
BEGIN

SELECT *
FROM tblFile 
WHERE 
  COALESCE(@title,title) like title 
  AND COALESCE(@director,director) like director
-- etc
END -- ALTER PROCEDURE
```

Comment: This approach will work but you're unlikely to get a decent query plan for most cases. Dynamic SQL or one procedure per @type would work better at the expense of a bit more typing.

Comment: @LoztInSpace You're right!! You could have multiple columns in `WHERE` clause using `AND`. That would be sufficient.

Comment: @sarwiknadkarny I am pretty sure that way will give the same problem. You will only get one plan. In future databases this may change but currently there is no real way to do this kind of thing efficiently other than choosing up front which query to run.

Comment: @LoztInSpace - I totally disagree that dynamic SQL will work better.  dynamic sql is expensive.  the real slowdown here is the like search with a `%` prefix.  This will never be fast on any non-small table.  if the column has a index then `@title = right(title,len(title)) or title like concat(@title,'%')` will be the best optimization (since that test is O(1) and prefixed test is O(N).  But this question is not about optimization.

Comment: @Hogan Actually yes you're correct.  The % prefix does mean a full table (or maybe index) scan is the only way to fulfil the query in any situation.  Had that not been the case I would have stood my ground :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you'd want to complicate this query. Its a simple query as it is :

```
SELECT * FROM tblFilm WHERE Title LIKE CONCAT('%', @value,'%');
```

This will do the search for you. There is no added benefit for you of adding the column names dynamically.

I understand that you would like to perform a search in the query. In this case, you can add multiple columns in the query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM tblFilm WHERE Title LIKE CONCAT('%', @value,'%') AND genre LIKE CONCAT('%', @genre_value,'%')
```

I think you'd get a better query execution plan for this. This is more maintainable in the long run. I can't see a benefit of passing the column name dynamically, at the very least in this case.

I'd suggest you to go the normal route.

Hope this helps!!!